# Music Playback in Visual Basic .NET

Tags: vb.net, desktop-application, vlc, audio-player

I am trying to create a desktop application that will play and pause music files the user has selected. However, the built-in audio playback (My.Computer.Audio) only plays .wav files, and it only has functions to play and stop.

I need something that can play, pause, stop, and hopefully read MP3 tags. I have looked into the VLC and Bass APIs, but I have no idea how to implement and use them. If anyone knows how to use said APIs, that would be great. I don't have a lot of experience, so please explain everything needed to import and utilize those APIs.

UPDATE: I am currently using an invisible Windows Media Player control, but it's slow and bulky.
Thanks

Comment: C# is going to be much easier for you, if you Google "vlc api .net" the bindings are C# not VB.  Time to learn C#?  Otherwise, you can try to create your own wrappers to use the unmanaged code "third party libraries" listed here:  http://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc.html

Comment: Actually I do see one VB result - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tWE-lGgdzss  (I'm surprised you didn't find this in your own Google search)

Comment: Dave S, I do plan on porting my app (Keklist) to C# WPF, but I want to finish the version I'm currently working on (2.3) before I do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options to integrate media playback into your application.

Personally, I would recommend using the VLC as it is well-documented, versatile and straight forward to use.

During installation of the VLC-Software, make sure that the ActiveX-Control option is checked. On your Visual Studio Project Settings page, go to "References", click "Add" and select "COM Objects" on the left hand side and in the list select the VLC-Control.

You can add the control directly to you form. If it is not displayed inside your toolbox, right click the toolbox list, choose select/add controls; once again select "COM Objects" on the left hand side and check the VLC-Control.

If it is not listed there, choose Browse and select axvlc.dll from VLC installation directory.

[Example: Toolbox / Choose Items dialog / Section "COM-Components" on Microsoft Visual Studio 2015](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6fRY.png)